# GNOME Tweaks not recognizing icons pack

Tags: icons, gnome-tweak-tool

I found the icon pack I'm trying to select here: https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1012430.

I extracted the folder and copied it to `~/themes`.

However, the icon pack is not listed in Icons menu. I tried restarting GNOME Tweaks, re-downloading the icon pack but nothing worked. I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the pack itself since I tried using other packs and they didn't work too.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: ~/. themes should be..

Comment: if its icons.. the below answer is exactly what you want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir $HOME/.icons
```

unpack the archive in this folder.